# integrating over the solutions of an implicit equation

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have an implicit equation in Mathematica, which I solve by using NSolve. Now, I need to weigh the various solutions according to a Gaussian, but I can't quite make it work. Here is my suggestion so far:

```
a = (4.2*10^(-5));
b = 4067;
c = 112;
sol[d_] := Select[NSolve[s == (1 + a^2*(2*Pi*1000*d)^2)/((1 + c/(1 + (s*b)/(1 + a^2*(2*Pi*1000*d)^2)))^2 + a^2*(2*Pi*1000*d)^2), {s}], Chop[(Im[s] /. #)] == 0 &][[1]][[1]][[2]];

NIntegrate[Exp[-v^2]*sol[v], {v, -2, 2}]
```

However, this does not work. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? What I want is pretty straightforward, but I've had some problems implementing it.

Best,
Niles.

Comment: I know the expression for "sol" is overwhelming, but Plot[sol[d],{d,-100,100}] should make it more "familiar". (it may take 5-10 seconds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this; the main points are to use the third argument to `NSolve` to specify the domain and to make sure the function `sol2` is called only on a numerical argument.

```
sol2[d_?NumericQ] := NSolve[s == (1 + 
     a^2*(2*Pi*1000*d)^2)/((1 + 
        c/(1 + (s*b)/(1 + a^2*(2*Pi*1000*d)^2)))^2 + 
     a^2*(2*Pi*1000*d)^2), {s}, Reals][[1]][[1]][[2]]

NIntegrate[Exp[-v^2]*sol2[v], {v, -2, 2}]
(* 1.66556 *)


Plot[Exp[-v^2]*sol2[v], {v, -2, 2}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: The reason why I explicitly wanted to integrate over v first was such that I could plot it as a function of d. So first NIntegrate over v (where the argument of sol is sol[d + v]) and then plot as a function of d. In my OP I just took the single point d=0